# What is the difference between people saying "nahegelegen" & "in der nähe"?

Tags: word-choice

i have read two versions of sentences :

'Das platz ist nahegelegen von Berlin' and 'Das platz ist in der nähe von Berlin'.

Is one of these sentences grammatically wrong? As far as I could interpret them, the meaning seems the same. Please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, notice that *Platz* is masculine. Therefore, it must be *der Platz*.

## In der Nähe

If something is *near* something else, you can use *in der Nähe*.

> Der Platz ist/ liegt in der Nähe von Berlin.
>
> The place is near Berlin.

## Nah liegen

A synonym of *in der Nähe* is *nah(e)*. In connection with the verb *liegen*, you can form *nah liegen* and *nahe gelegen sein*, both meaning *to be (located) near/ close to*.

> Der Platz liegt nah bei Berlin.
>
> The place is close to Berlin.

or

> Der Platz ist nahe Berlin gelegen.
>
> The place is located near Berlin.

Notice that in both expressions the words are written separately.

If you want to say that something is *nearby*, you can use the past participle *nahe gelegen/ nahegelegen*, which can be written as one or two words (see [canoo.net, §36.2.2](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Adjektiv.html)):

> am nahe gelegenen/ nahegelegenen Platz.

## Naheliegen

There is also the compound verb *naheliegen*, of which usually only the participle *naheliegend* is used, and which means *obvious*!

> Dieser Gedanke ist naheliegend.
>
> This thought is obvious.